# Which command would you use if you want to remove the password assigned to a group

Tags: password, group

Suppose I have one or more groups (as in the user database as backed by `/etc/group` or LDAP or NIS+...) configured with a password (for the `sg` or `newgrp` commands).

Which command would you use to remove the password assigned to such a particular group?

Does it depend on which kind of user database is used (`/etc/passwd,shadow`, NIS+, LDAP...) or on the system?

I'm on Linux, but knowing the method on other systems would also be interesting.

Comment: What password is this? That is, where is this password being used or assigned?

Comment: Use `gpasswd -r [group]`.

Comment: Why would anybody downvote this question?

Comment: Probably because it shows the OP didn't make any effort on own research...